# R time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only, yet my date is in said format

Tags: r, ggplot2, posixct

when altering my dataset so that the ExpDayHour column is in the correct format (posixct) R tells me that time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only when trying to make a ggplot of n in function of the RefillRate, ExpDayHour, FlowerNo and Offset.

i expected to generate a ggplot where the date and time were on the x axis, the refillrate was the color of the curve and n was on the y-axis.
here is my script:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggthemes)
library(scales)
preds = read.csv("preds_2.csv")

# Convert ExpDayHour to POSIXct format with timezone set to "GMT"
preds$ExpDayHour <- as.POSIXct(preds$ExpDayHour, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")

# Create a scatter plot with facets and color gradient
ggplot(data = preds, aes(x = ExpDayHour, y = n, color = RefillRate)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%d %H:%M", breaks = date_breaks("2 hours"), timezone = "GMT")     +
  facet_grid(. ~ FlowerNo + Offset) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") +
  labs(x = "Date and Time", y = "Number of visits", color = "RefillRate") +
  ggtitle("Relationship between the number of flower visits and the time, refill rate and flower     number") +
  theme_economist_white() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 18),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 16)) +
  annotate("text", x = 0, y = 0, label = "Source: My Data")
```

and this is my dataset:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19rprT4TB1TiFkhXIUzzi-WhBKb-z1fVg/view?usp=sharing

and a data sample:

```
    structure(list(FlowerNo = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), Row = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Column = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Colony = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), ColonySize = c(77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 
77L, 77L, 77L), RefillRate = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L), ExpDayHour = structure(c(-2208989361, -2208985761, -2208982161, 
-2208978561, -2208974961, -2208971361, -2208967761, -2208964161, 
-2208960561, -2208956961), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
)), n = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 3L), Offset = c(2.19722457733622, 
2.19722457733622, 2.19722457733622, 2.19722457733622, 2.19722457733622, 
2.19722457733622, 2.19722457733622, 2.19722457733622, 2.19722457733622, 
2.19722457733622), ExpDay = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), ExpHour = 0:9, obs = 1:10, model = c("model3", "model3", 
"model3", "model3", "model3", "model3", "model3", "model3", "model3", 
"model3"), fit = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lower.CI = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.01202890791274, -3.03611841847294, -3.03615011445332
), upper.CI = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.01202890791274, 3.03611841847294, 
3.03615011445332), lower.PI = c(`1` = 0, `2` = 0, `3` = 0, `4` = 0, 
`5` = 0, `6` = 0, `7` = 0, `8` = 0, `9` = 0, `10` = 0), upper.PI = c(`1` = 0, 
`2` = 0, `3` = 0, `4` = 0, `5` = 0, `6` = 0, `7` = 0, `8` = 81.2233791197293, 
`9` = 244.247330806024, `10` = 244.824524252859)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    n = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 3L), ExpDayHour = structure(c(-2208989361, 
    -2208985761, -2208982161, -2208978561, -2208974961, -2208971361, 
    -2208967761, -2208964161, -2208960561, -2208956961), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), Offset = c(2.19722457733622, 2.19722457733622, 
    2.19722457733622, 2.19722457733622, 2.19722457733622, 2.19722457733622, 
    2.19722457733622, 2.19722457733622, 2.19722457733622, 2.19722457733622
    ), obs = 1:10, FlowerNo = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), RefillRate = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
        9L, 10L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: I’m not able to access your data. You may need to change the sharing settings, or (preferably) add a sample of your data directly to your post by pasting the result of `dput(head(preds_1, 10))`.

Comment: @zephryl i added a sample and also updated the privacy on the csv file

Comment: The dates in your example look like "1/1/1900 0:00" but the format in your `as.POSIXct` looks like "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S". Those formats do not match. Have you checked the values in your dataset before plotting to make sure they are valid? When I run the code I just see all NA values.

Comment: @MrFlick i used a different subset and now it shouldn't give NA values.

Answer (score 0):

As @MrFlick points out, the datetime format you provide needs to match your data. From the sample data I am guessing a bit that it is month/day/Year, so note `%m/%d/%Y` in the code below.
Your annotation is going to throw an error if you try and give `x = 0` as the position, since your x-axis is now a time series. One alternative, applied below, is to add caption text, `labs(caption = 'text')` and left-align it in your `theme`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(ExpDayHour = as.POSIXct(strptime(ExpDayHour, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), tz = "GMT")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(ExpDayHour, n, color = RefillRate)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%d %H:%M", breaks = scales::breaks_width("2 hours"), timezone = "GMT") +
  facet_grid(. ~ FlowerNo + Offset) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") +
  labs(x = "Date and Time", y = "Number of visits", color = "RefillRate",
       caption = "Source: My Data") +
  ggtitle("Relationship between the number of flower visits and the time, refill rate and flower     number") +
  ggthemes::theme_economist_white() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 18),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 16),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: that is a step in the right direction! thanks already! however, when i run this code i receive this error message: Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number.

Comment: Hi Alexander. Do you receive this error when running the above code with the sample data you shared?

Comment: Hi Seth, I managed to figure it out! thanks